# alarm does not ring in android from device storage?

Tags: android, media-player, ringtone, ringtonemanager

i was working on a battery alarm application that selects ring from the device storage i used `ListPreference` for selecting ring from the users device . i tested that app on my Lenovo TAB 7 . i only got ringtone available from manufactures . alarm rang when battery was full .

again for testing purpose i tried application in Xiaomi Redmi 5A . i got all the ringtone or music available on the phone when i choose ringtone for alarm . but it does not rang when it should . both phone have same application with same version no changes at all .

I Tried following :

- i checked that ringtone path is selected and stored into preference .
- when i was checking for preference i got that path of Ringtone selected from Lenovo starts with something like contet://......
- when path of Ringtone selected from Xiaomi Redmi 5A starts from something like storage://.....

i think i am getting this problem due to these reason . i tried to find some solution but got nothing . i am playing music or ringtone with `MediaPlayer` .

Thank You in Advance

Comment: You should try to get the Absolute path from the Uri.

Comment: @Chandan kushwaha how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

so finally i got answer my self .

there was just a basic thing i used `setResource` method on MediaPlayer object so it could play music from the phone .

but it was not working on Xiaomi mobiles . so i tried to pass path in constructor as we normally do with our raw resources . Voila it is working good . so just pass uri path in constructor it will work on the all devices including android Q (or 10)